# Is it safe to use an Events with ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject?

Tags: .net, multithreading

The documentation for [RegisterWaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9f75h7a.aspx) says

> Using a Mutex for waitObject does not
>   provide mutual exclusion for the
>   callbacks because the underlying Win32
>   API uses the default WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT
>   flag, so each callback is dispatched
>   on a separate thread pool thread.
>   Instead of a Mutex, use a Semaphore
>   with a maximum count of 1.

and (in the documentation for the WaitHandle argument) it says

> Use a WaitHandle other than Mutex

This seems to imply that it's safe to use an Event -- is it?

Would there be any difference between using an AutoResetEvent and a ManualResetEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are fine. I think I've only ever used events with this method

Re auto vs. manual reset events, the [documentation for the underlying Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025(VS.85).aspx) says that only the object that signalled the end of the wait is affected:

> The function modifies the state of
>   some types of synchronization objects.
>   Modification occurs only for the
>   object or objects whose signaled state
>   caused the function to return.

Manual reset events never change state unless you do it, well, manually; I'd expect an auto reset event to reset itself only if it was the one that caused the wait to finish. You would only notice this if you had two auto-reset events signalled simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Both `AutoResetEvent` and `ManualResetEvent` derive from `WaitHandle` which is the prescribed use case here.  So yes, using both of these classes is safe (if used within the guidelines of the documentation of course).